# uploaded product images show only on front end

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I was finally able to upload product images to a website using magento 1.7.0.2 but the images only appear on the front end and not visible via admin panel. I find it rather strange. Can anyone please tell me how to fix this? I have flushed the cache and reindexed several times but no apparent change.

Comment: I believe this somewhat related to `.htaccess` file. What is your hosting provider ?

Comment: When you go to Admin -> Product -> image tab ...and mouse over the image what happen? Try inspect the image to see the url path and copy and paste it in your browser... see how to inspect image @  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmFAUnWTV8w

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but we had the same problem just now.

It seems that the import we did (the .csv file), missed a few fields, therefore entries were missing in the `media_gallery` table in Magento.

We couldn't repeat the import again, because the customer has already entered new and fixed a lot of the imported products.

We followed the guide [here](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-fix-the-issue-product-images-missing-in-backend-but-not-in-frontend/) (thnx MagePsycho) to get the things sorted.

The guide needed a litle bit of fixing (manually entering the table names) since we were doing the fix on Magento 1.8, and had a bit of trouble with the table prefixes.